# A simple css torn border without images?

Tags: css

What would be the simplest way to create a torn border only on one side of a div block without loading external images?

Comment: Could you, at the *very* least, show us what you mean by a 'torn border'? I'd suggest *also* adding your current relevant ([Minimal, Complete, Verified and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML to your question and explaining what you've already tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think unless english is your 5th language I find it painfully obvious what the asker means by torn border.

Comment: @Dr. in which case please feel free to edit the question and let me know what the OP might have meant.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ripped effect with css background gradient:

**HTML**

```css
.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(#2B3A48 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, #2B3A48 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2B3A48 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, #2B3A48 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#2B3A48 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, #2B3A48 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#2B3A48 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, #2B3A48 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 0px 100%, 9px 27px, 9px 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

### Want Transparancy?

Simply replace the hex colour value with an an rgba value.

- The hex value of the blue colour used is **#2B3A48**
- This same blue in rgba is **rgba(43,58,72,0)**
- **rgba** stands for **Red Green Blue Alpha** where alpha is transparancy
  rated from **0** to **1**.
- So replace the alpha value of **rgba(43,58,72,0)** with how transparant
  you want it to be.

**EXAMPLE**

rgba(43,58,72,**0.5**) = **50%** transparant.

## ANSWER

The simple answer is replace all instances of **#2B3A48** with **rgba(43,58,72,0.5)**

```css
.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #272220 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #272220 -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #272220 33.33%, rgba(43, 58, 72, 0.5) 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 0px 100%, 9px 27px, 9px 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

*If you want the black transparant replace the black colour with an rgba value instead.*

Comment: This is great - I'm wondering if its possible to implement with a transparent background so its just one color and transparency? I stuggled with it...

Comment: Sure transparancy is easy. See edits above.

Comment: Any ideas why when I paste this code in my project the triangles are rotated by 90deg?

Comment: @Brackets The only reason the code would be different is if you have overriding styles. Check the browsers web inspector to see what additional styles are being applied.